# AngularJS Select, Clear selected Value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Trying to create a simple List Box with only 1 item that can be selected at a time and the possibility to have 0 item selected.

I tried many thing but each time i get a selected white line in my select...

How can i achieve to have a List Box like in C#/VB ? that i can clear the selected value and see no line selected in my select!

My select code

```
<select 
    size="5"
    style="width: 100px"
    ng-model="vm.current.selection"
    ng-options="role as role.Name for role in vm.roles">
</select>
```

EDIT :

It's fun to see 2 people doesn't understand the question and said it's impossible and when i get a solution to my actual problem, they do -1....

Comment: this appears to be a standard HTML select box;  it's not really clear what your question is here.  HTML select boxes only allow a single item to be selected by default...

Comment: I want it to have 0 selected item, just like a C# List Box

Comment: that won't work in HTML / Angular.  Once you select an item, then `vm.current.selection` will go from `null` to a value;  you would have to change the value back to `null` to simulate a "deselect".  you *might* be able to add an option that is `""`, but that wouldn't be selected automatically when deselecting another option, and it doesn't *exactly* do the same thing as setting `vm.current.selection` to `null`....

Comment: that doesn't work. null value is adding a white item to the select. that's wrong for my case. i need it have 0 selected value.

Comment: you can't have the model have a value that isn't in the list.  Angular/HTML doesn't support that configuration.  When your `vm.current.selection` is set to a value not on the list, a blank row is created, for the two way binding to function.

Comment: @Vince that's not possible since when using ngOptions, angular will create a null option by default.

Comment: So my only options is to create multiple select ?

Comment: multiple select works differently;  your `ng-model` is then an `array` of selected elements, and it is valid to have an array with `0` elements.

Comment: Yea, that's what i'm working on at the moment, but i can't figure where i need to splice my array to get only 1 active item in the list. ng-change is not reflected in my list if i change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a solution to anybody that want to create a simple List Box like C# with only 1 item selected at a time or 0 item selected.

It's not beautifull to do it this way, but it's the way i found it work!

So here is my code to achieve:

```
vm.current = {
    selection: []
};

$scope.$watchCollection(
    function (scope) {
        return (vm.current.selection);
    },
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue.length == 2) {
            var index = findRoleIndexWithId(vm.current.selection, oldValue[0].Id);
            vm.current.selection.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
);
```